# Why is the maximum BLE Tx power 4dBm?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

Does anyone know why BLE Tx power is 4dBm maximum?  Does it have anything to do with coin cell battery peak current limit (15mA?)

Answer (score 6):

Because that is the FCC limit for Class II Bluetooth (10 meter range) transmitters. The FCC determined that 4 dBm was adequate to support the range, and more would increase interference with other stations.

Answer (score 0):

4 dBm is the maxiumum Tx power of the IC that you're using. It can be higher, for example the [nRF52820](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Low-power-short-range-wireless/nRF52820) can do a maximum of +8 dBm.

The Bluetooth specification says the maximum transmission power can be +20 dBm. This is in table 3.1 in Vol 6, Part A, Section 3.

[image]